# template bootstrap jquery not working after redirect in angular

Tags: angular

i have a bootstrap template that i bought. When I place it in src/template and I do the configuration in angular.json.

When I login and redirect with this.router.navigate(['/staff/dashboard']). The buttons in the template don't work (because jquery doesn't work). But if the /staff/dashboard url is reloaded without a redirect, everything works normally. What is the correct setup so that when redirecting after logging in all assets are loaded correctly

[image]

angular.json config:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/pace.min.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/simplebar/css/simplebar.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/metismenu/css/metisMenu.min.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/pace.min.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/app.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/icons.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/semi-dark.css",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/css/header-colors.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/simplebar/js/simplebar.min.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/metismenu/js/metisMenu.min.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/plugins/chartjs/js/chart.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/js/app.js",
              "src/assets/template/rocker/assets/js/pace.min.js"
            ]
```

Login service:

```
doLogin():void {
    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      this.loginForm.disable();
      this.loginService.doUserLogin(this.loginForm.controls['emailUn'].value, this.loginForm.controls['pw'].value).subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
            if(res){
              this.error = false;
              this.router.navigate(['/staff/dashboard'])
            }
            this.error = true;
          },
          error: () => {
            this.error = true;
            this.loginForm.enable();
            this.doReset();
          },
      });
      this.error = false;
    } else {
      this.doReset();
      this.error = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you see any error on the console ?

Comment: there is no error on console log.

Comment: This is not a Bootstrap question. It's an angular routing question.